# Выборка и слияние двух запросов по горизонтали

Tags: sql-server

Есть две таблицы с следующими видами:

```
tbl_invoice
----------------------------------
inv_id | inv_code | inv_nettotal |
----------------------------------
  1    |   inv_1  |    2000      |
  2    |   inv_2  |    3000      |
----------------------------------

tbl_payment
------------------------------------------
p_id |  inv_id  |   p_date   |  p_amount  |
-------------------------------------------
  1  |     2    | 01.01.2016 |    1000    |
  2  |     1    | 08.02.2016 |    1500    |
  3  |     2    | 10.02.2016 |    1500    |
  4  |     1    | 10.02.2016 |    500     |
-------------------------------------------
```

Нужно обьеденить их так чтобы получилось следующее:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| inv_id | inv_code | inv_nettotal | 01.01.2016 | 08.02.2016 | 10.02.2016 | amount_due |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |  inv_1   |     2000     |    0       |     1500   |     500    |      0     |
|   2    |  inv_2   |     3000     |    1000    |     0      |     1500   |      500   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: join таблиц и pivot transformation

Comment: А примерчик можно?

Comment: google: "mssql pivot" правда сразу предупрежу, что все колонки в SQL должны быть описаны заранее, так что динамически не выйдет. только динамическим же формированием запроса. А вообще есть смысл задуматься о разворачивании в горизонталь уже на клиенте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается достаточно сложный скрипт, состоящий из динамического формирования столбцов для PIVOT, а так же для других операций. При этом стоит учесть, что он формируется как строка и итоговый скрипт будет в итоге формировать тоже в строку.

В итоге получается вот такой франкенштейн

```
declare @DynamicPivotQuery as nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnName as nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnNameMax as nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnNameSum as nvarchar(max)

select @ColumnName= isnull(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + quotename(p_date)
from (select distinct p_date from tbl_payment) as Dates

select @ColumnNameMax= isnull(@ColumnNameMax + ',','') 
       + 'max(' + quotename(p_date) + ') as ' + quotename(p_date)
from (select distinct p_date from tbl_payment) as Dates 

select @ColumnNameSum = isnull(@ColumnNameSum + '+','') 
       + 'isnull(' + quotename(p_date) + ', 0)'
from (select distinct p_date from tbl_payment) as Dates

set @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'
  select inv.inv_id, inv.inv_code, inv.inv_nettotal,' + @ColumnName + ', inv.inv_nettotal - ('+@ColumnNameSum+') as amount_due
  from tbl_invoice as inv 
  left join (
    select inv_id, ' + @ColumnNameMax + '
    from tbl_payment
    pivot(sum(p_amount) for p_date in (' + @ColumnName + ')) as PVTTable 
    group by inv_id) as pay on pay.inv_id = inv.inv_id'

exec sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Конечно, скрипт с разворачиванием столбцов в горизонталь гораздо лучше, когда имена заранее известны. Вот так он выглядел бы, если бы даты были фиксированы. Если в вашем приложение есть возможность их определить перед отправкой на выполнение скрипта и динамически сформировать, лучше использовать его. Или выбрать другой подход в формировании итогов на клиенте.

```
select inv.inv_id, 
        inv.inv_code, 
        inv.inv_nettotal,
        [2016-01-01],
        [2016-02-08],
        [2016-02-10], 
        inv.inv_nettotal - (isnull([2016-01-01], 0)+isnull([2016-02-08], 0)+isnull([2016-02-10], 0)) as amount_due
from tbl_invoice as inv 
left join (
        select inv_id, max([2016-01-01]) as [2016-01-01],max([2016-02-08]) as [2016-02-08],max([2016-02-10]) as [2016-02-10]
        from tbl_payment
        pivot(sum(p_amount) for p_date in ([2016-01-01],[2016-02-08],[2016-02-10])) as PVTTable 
        group by inv_id) as pay on pay.inv_id = inv.inv_id
```

Comment: Спасибо друг! Подправиль немного под себя и все идеально подошло. То что надо)